# Make post calls on hold

Tags: node.js, heroku, sequelize.js

I have a Node.js application and I deployed it on Heroku. The API calls are made from a native app. I am using Postgresql for database (Sequelize as orm) and my db allows maximum 20 connections.

When those connections are full I get an error message "too many connections for role ..." and if there's a post request made at that moment it's not saved.

Is there a way to put the request "on hold" and to complete it as soon as the connection is available?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing built into the platform that will allow you to arbitrarily queue requests based on conditions at the application level. Instead of dropping these requests outright you could implement a connection pool with Sequelize (docs [here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/installation/usage.html#options) and [here](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/classes/Sequel/ConnectionPool.html)) which should improve the user experience by limiting the number of connections consumed by the app. This way your application will hold onto those requests for a short while (likely until the platform times them out) but it will at least give your app a chance to process them.